# Undefined references when using -fsanitize=address

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, linker, g++

I have `-fsanitize=address` in the compiler option, however, I don't know why I get multiple `undefined references` error. If I remove that option, there is no problem.

```
g++ -O1 -fsanitize=address -g3 -fPIC -std=c++11 -Wall \
    -I/usr/local/cuda-11.2/include -I. -I/home/project/libcuda -I/home/project/src \
    -c trace_driven.cc -o ../build/release/trace_driven.o
```

The errors are related to STL vector. There are many instances, see this example:

```
/home/project/trace-driven/trace_driven.cc:420: undefined reference to `__asan_report_load8'
```

Comment: You shows a _compile_ command (which produced no errors), then a _link_ error without showing the link command and without saying what version of `g++` or which platform you are using. That's not the best way to ask questions.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know why I get `multiple undefined references` error.

We can't know either -- you haven't shown you *link* command.

Possibly because you didn't specify `-fsanitize=address` on the link command (you need to in order for `g++` to supply correct libraries at link time), in addition to specifying that option on compile line.

Comment: I will provide more information if I can narrow it with a minimal example.

Answer (score -1):

I tested your command line with `clang++` and it worked. But it seems that you need to use `-lasan` or `-static-libasan` for `g++` to link additional libraries.

I found these samples [here](https://gist.github.com/kwk/4171e37f4bcdf7705329):

```
using-gcc:
    g++-4.8 -o main-gcc -lasan -O -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer main.cpp && \
    ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1 ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=$(shell which llvm-symbolizer) ./main-gcc

using-gcc-static:
    g++-4.8 -o main-gcc-static -static-libstdc++ -static-libasan -O -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer main.cpp && \
    ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1 ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=$(shell which llvm-symbolizer) ./main-gcc-static

using-clang:
    clang -o main-clang -x c++ -O -g -fsanitize=address main.cpp && \
    ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1 ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=$(shell which llvm-symbolizer) ./main-clang
```

Comment: `g++-4.8 -o ... -lsan ...` is _plain_ wrong (order of objects and libraries on the link line matters, and yours is wrong).

Comment: @EmployedRussian it was not mine and I just directly linked from the gist source.